# Video streaming on android phone

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer, android-video-player, mpeg-2

What is the best API for video streaming on Android?  The Video is basically MPEG 2, kept on server, I want to stream to my Android phone which is having the decoder and our own player. 
(decoding is happening on the phone itself). 
**The requirement is the delay should be as minimum as possible for smooth decoding  and play back.**

What about Gstreamer, is it a most efficient way?

Any suggestions?

Rgrds,

Heshsham

Answer (score 0):

may example  given at http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/checkout helps you